# Facebook login not working with app request on IOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I have implemented sending Facebook app request in my IOs app using FBWebDialogs like this:

```
 [FBWebDialogs
 presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
 message:@"<message>"
 title:nil
 parameters:nil //params
 handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
}
```

Also I implemented Facebook login like described here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.2 - used custom login button

And now I have following issue (steps to reproduce):

1) User A send app request to user B

2) User B receive notification in Facebook and click the link - navigate to App Store to my app

3) User B download app and press login with Facebook

4) User B AGAIN NAVIGATED to APP STORE ??????

If user download add normally without app request than he can login successfully with Facebook login button in my app

[image: configuration of my facebook app]

Any help will be appreciated